# Java - Parsing Text File

Tags: java, parsing, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have an input text file in this format:

```
<target1> : <dep1> <dep2> ...
<target2> : <dep1> <dep2> ...
...
```

And a method that takes two parameters

```
function(target, dep);
```

I need to get this parsing to call my method with each target and dep eg:

```
function(target1, dep1);
function(target1, dep2);
function(target1, ...);
function(target2, dep1);
function(target2, dep2);
function(target2, ...);
```

What would be the most efficient way to call `function(target,dep)` on each line of a text file?  I tried fooling around with the scanner and string.split but was unsuccessful.  I'm stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with Scaner?

Comment: Can you paste the code you wrote?

Comment: No code to post.  My original thought was to save each line into a string but since the total number to dep's is unknown it would need some sort of loop correct?

Comment: Read the file line by line... split each line on ':' then the first part is the target, and then the second part is all the deps, which can be separated by splitting on space

Answer (score 11):

- Read line into `String myLine`
- split `myLine` on `:` into `String[] array1`
- split `array1[1]` on `' '` into `String[] array2`
- Iterate through `array2` and call `function(array1[0], array2[i])`

So ...

```
FileReader input = new FileReader("myFile");
BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
String myLine = null;

while ( (myLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null)
{    
    String[] array1 = myLine.split(":");
    // check to make sure you have valid data
    String[] array2 = array1[1].split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
        function(array1[0], array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Load each line into its own string?  Or use while(hasNextLine)?  I understand the splitting and iterate but how would each line become it's own string?

Comment: I've just provided this info :)

Comment: I understand it now.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: added the `FileReader` and loop.

Answer (score 2):

The firstly you have to read line from file and after this split read line, so your code should be like:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("your file name");
// or using Scaner
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // split string and call your function
}
```

Comment: where should the file be stored? in the project folder or src folder?