# Libgdx read internal text file for android

Tags: java, android, file, text, libgdx

I am trying to load some data from an internal `.txt` file. After some efforts with `FileHandle` the only I thing I've accomplished is to put this `.txt` file into a string variable. Instead of this string I need the integers that are stored inside:

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("txt/questions.txt");
String lines = handle.readString(); `
```

Part of txt file:0

```
#a)1! b)0,350,190,185!      c)180,1247,180,153!           d)710,970,124,101!             e)615,1105,175,120! //sheep
#a)2! b)208,344,248,191!    c)403,957,142,127!            d)655,1250,142,130!            e)0,1075,263,150! // elafi
#a)3! b)460,344,164,200!    c)10,1232,165,155!            d)245,915,150,133!             e)268,1083,235,145! //elephant
#a)4! b)624,344,234,190!    c)835,260,150,55!             d)500,1228,155,172!            e)800,1117,185,108! //horse
#a)5! b)858,330,167,203!    c)10,890,220,174!             d)822,1235,178,145!            e)575,943,128,141! //rabbit
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "parse" your text file.  You could write a simple parser for your text file format (there is nothing special in Libgdx to support parsing text files, so any standard Java features like [Java - Parsing Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819772/java-parsing-text-file) OR http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html might help).

Alternatively, it might be simpler put your text file in a format that is easy for existing Libgdx code to parse.  That generally means ["JSON"](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/JsonParsing). JSON is not a Libgdx file format, so there are lots of tools and tutorials explaining JSON.  (This format makes more sense if your file is generated by a tool and isn't maintained by a human directly.)